# How to use VScrollBar and HScrollBar together with a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, scrollbar, richtextbox

In my form I have a `RichTextBox`. I also have a `VScrollBar` and `HScrollBar`. I set the `RichTextBox` property `ScrollBars` to `None` so I can use the new scroll bars for it. Thats where I hit a problem, how do I do it? I searched online and found nothing for "c# richtextbox vscrollbar"

Please add references to articles to your answers so I can learn how it works.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question... Are you trying to disable / hide the scroll bars of your RichTextBox? Are you trying to enable them? Are you trying to use a different set of scroll bars all together?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to do what you want.  The best thing I can thing of would be to try and find the right position in the text, then Select() and ScrollToCaret().  I usually only use that trick to force a TextBox/RichTextBox to scroll to the very end, though.  It wouldn't be very easy to use it for what you want.

Is there a reason why you don't want to use the default scroll bars?

In my experience, I've rarely had any luck anytime I've tried to use custom scroll bars in C# - especially with a control that has the ability to auto-scroll built it.

The only time I've used them without too much trouble is with a third party control that didn't have an auto-scroll capability.